# React Navigation trigger when routeName changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation for navigate screen. I used nested navigation, `TabNavigator` and `StackNavigator`. How can I know in current screen has been swipe / change to other screen and change the `state` inside the screen without using `Redux` . I try to get `this.props.navigation.state.routeName` , it get the routeName of the screen, but how to trigger when routeName has change

```
const mainNav = TabNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Live: {
   screen: LiveScreen,
  },
  Radio: {
   screen: RadioScreen,
  },
} );

export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: mainNav},
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no way to track swipe gestures in react navigation. You can use hacks to achieve this, But mostly all of them requires hooking react navigation with redux.

Best way to track your screens will be to use react redux and hook the state with appState. This will give you most control over navigation and you can also use redux actions to control navigations along with other business stuff f in the app.

Simplest method to use [react navigation with redux](https://moduscreate.com/blog/react-navigation-redux-in-react-native-applications/)

You can refer

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1063

Comment: hi, I cant really understand how redux work. Any other example ?